# choose another link before interval finish make the function crash

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a tabbing function, inside the function i create interval to hide the content.  but i find the bug that if i click another tab before the content is fully hide. the tabbing will stop functioning.

```
$('.panel a').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var _thumbs =$(this).attr('data-name');
    show_content();
    $('#'+_thumbs).removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.close').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    hide_content();
    });
function hide_content(){
  $('.sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-show');
  setTimeout(backtoNormal, 1000);
}

function show_content(){
    $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
  if(!$('.sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-show')){
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('hidden').addClass('sidebar-show');
  }
}

function backtoNormal(){
        $('.sidebar').addClass('hidden');
    $('.single-page').addClass('hidden'); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mg4t9cnt/

Comment: Add event as a param for your functions in on()

Comment: sorry but still not working

Answer (score 0):

well i just use

```
$('.sidebar').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend'),                    function(event) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass('hidden');
  }
```

thank you guys